# What is the default value of Vector<char> in c++?

Tags: c++

A simple question, but I have been unable to find a conclusive answer online or in the textbook I am using:

I have a `Map<string, Vector<char>>` and I need to know if a string key I am using is a defined key in the `Map`. I know that if the key is undefined, `.get(key)` will return the default value for the value type, but I am unsure what the default value for `Vector<char>` would be.

Comment: If you're talking about `std::vector<char>` then the default value is an empty vector. If you're talking about some other `Vector`, then what are you talking about? And what is `.get(key)`?

Comment: What are `Map` and `Vector` here? Are you sure you don't mean `map` and `vector`?

Comment: I'm clearly new to this. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should clarify your question (see first two comments.)

Comment: You can easily find online the default value: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector Quote: `1) Default constructor. Constructs empty container.`

Answer (score 2):

It's `std::vector<char>()`. 
In addition one can say that the default constructor generates the defaulted object of that specific class.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unsure what the default value for `vector<char >` would be

It will be a default constructed `std::vector` object.

However, a better way to detect whether the `map` has entry corresponding to a given key is to use `find` and check whether the returned value is a dereferenceable `iterator`.

```
if ( myMap.find(myKey) != myMap.end() )
{
   // The map has an entry corresponding to myKey
}
else
{
   // The map does not have an entry corresponding to myKey
}
```

Comment: The end iterator is a *valid* iterator. I think you mean *dereferenceable*.

Answer (score 0):

A default `vector<char>` will be one constructed using the default constructor, so the same as doing:

```
std::vector<char> charVector;
```

Such a vector will be empty and that's pretty much all that can be said about it.

Answer (score -1):

`std::vector<char>` is an empty vector by default.